# Как настроить Xdebug для Twig в Opencart

Tags: opencart, phpstorm, openserver, twig

Насколько мне известно для того что бы xdebug работал с twig нужно указать путь к папке с кешом. [image] Я пробывал 2 варианта C: \ OSPanel \ domains \ oc.test \ storage \ cache и
C: \ OSPanel \ domains \ oc.test \ upload \ system \ storage \ cache но они оба не работают. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: какая версия шторма?

Comment: @Kirill 2019.1.3